# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript', when i have a NSDictionary

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm getting this error: "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'", in this line of code:

```
var messages = sections[startDay]
```

This the sections's declaration:

```
var sections = [NSDate:[Message]]()
```

And te startDay

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let startDay = calendar.startOfDay(for: date as Date)
```

Comment: Where is your use of `NSDictionary`? You seem to be using Swift dictionaries, not `NSDictionary` (and that's a good thing).

Comment: You have to use Date instead of NSDate and Calendar instead of NSCalendar

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_ ? Have you really changed the declaration of `sections` to `var sections = [Date:[Message]]()` ?

Comment: yeah, i already try it, and it doesn't work. I'm still getting the error

Comment: @EdwardPizzurro Can you update your question with new code and if possible show the screenshot also where you are getting this error.

Comment: Why don't you try to explain what _it doesn't work_? If you say, _I'm still getting the error_, you should show the whole code getting the error, and show the error message your get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is completely misleading. The real reason is you can't subscript an `[NSDate: [Message]]` dictionary with a key of type `Date`. `Date` is Swift, `NSDate` is Objective-C. Same with `String / NSString, Data / NSData, Calendar / NSCalendar`, etc.

Unless you have a really good reason to do otherwise, always use the Swift data types in Swift.

```
var sections = [Date: [Message]]()
let date = Date()
let startDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)

var messages = sections[startDay]
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried that, and i released that in my code, i was putting something wrong, but the changes worked!